# Format string from scientific notation to string without it

Tags: c, format

I have a string like "6544556E+17" .
I have to convert it to string without exponential format like "654455600000000000000000".

How to do this in C?

<sup>*Note: Not in C++ as the question was mistakenly tagged earlier.*</sup>

Comment: sscanf() and sprintf() will do?

Comment: First you need to choose *one* programming language. Either C or C++.

Comment: I have to do it in C.

Comment: Basically, convert the string to `double` with `strtod()` or `sscanf()`; then format it using `snprintf()` with an appropriate fixed-point format: `%.0f` looks appropriate for the sample value, but would be wildly inappropriate for `6.544556E-23`.  Alternatively, you can do an analysis of the string and apply padding in the appropriate places — this would avoid some of the vagaries of floating point conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the string to double using `atof` and then converting it back to a string (while using `std::fixed` to make sure scientific notation is avoided).

```
#include <sstream>
std::string str = "6544556E+17";
double d = atof(str.c_str());

std::ostringstream strs;
strs << std::fixed << d;
std::string no_scientic_str = strs.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision` to display a floating point number without the decimal point and the exponentiation form.

```
std::ostringstream str;
str << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0) << 6544556E+17 << std::endl;
std::string s = str.str();
```

However, on my machine, I don't get "654455600000000000000000" in `s`. I get "654455599999999987941376". I'm going to guess that 654455600000000000000000 is not precisely representable using IEEE floating point representation. I am not sure what logic you'll have to employ to transform "654455599999999987941376" to "654455600000000000000000".